# Can't choose auto suggest on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an auto suggest function on a website, where it gets the categories from the database.

It works perfect on desktop computers and laptops, but when I open the page on my iphone for example, it suggest the categories, but I can't click on it to autofill the input box?

My jQuery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $(".search").keyup(function() {
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;
        if (searchid != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search/search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    jQuery("#result").live("click", function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#searchid').val(decoded);
    });
    jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
            jQuery("#result").fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('#searchid').click(function() {
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });
});

</script>
```

And my HTML

```
<input type="text" class="search" id="searchid" name="tekst placeholder="What are you looking for?">

<div id="result">
</div>
```

I just can't see where the problem is, as mentioned the auto suggest works perfect, but it's when I want to click on the suggested word, nothing happens.

You can see the site here: http://goo.gl/YMfsn9

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry.. A friend of mine just dropped by and the answer is to make the div "pointable" with CSS

```
.search 
{
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

So fortunately the problem wasn't that big :-)